# I made the property observable but it is not visible on the screen

Tags: c#, .net, maui, android-mvvm, maui-community-toolkit

In this application that I developed with MVVM, counter, question, score and answer were displayed on the screen before adding the `Observable` feature. When I added the `Observable` feature, these started not to appear on the screen.

[image]

MultiplicationPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.Models"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.Views.MultiplicationPage"
             x:DataType="viewModels:MultiplicationPageViewModel"
             Title="MultiplicationPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="Score: " FontSize="18" />
            <Label Text="{Binding playerModal.Score}" FontSize="18" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="Time Remaining: " FontSize="18" />
            <Label Text="{Binding playerModal.TimeReaming}" FontSize="18" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="Question: " FontSize="18" />
            <Label Text="{Binding playerModal.Question}" FontSize="18" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <Entry Placeholder="Enter Your Answer" Text="{Binding playerModal.Answer}" FontSize="18" />
        
        <Button Text="Submit" Command="{Binding SubmitAnswerCommand }" FontSize="18" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MultiplicationPageViewModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using MauiApp2.Models;
using MauiApp2.Services;
using MauiApp2.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MauiApp2.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MultiplicationPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PlayerModal> PlayerDetails { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PlayerModal>();
        public PlayerModal playerModal { get; set; } = new PlayerModal();
        public ICommand SubmitAnswerCommand { get; }
        public MultiplicationPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            
            playerModal.Score = 0;
            playerModal.TimeReaming= 60;
            SubmitAnswerCommand = new Command(SubmitAnswer);

            // Create a question as an example
            GenerateQuestion();
            // Start the timer
            StartTimer();
        }
        
        [RelayCommand]
        public void GenerateQuestion()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int number1 = random.Next(1, 11); // a random number between 1 and 10
            int number2 = random.Next(1, 11); // a random number between 1 and 10

            // playerModal.Answer = (number1 * number2).ToString(); Automatic Answer
            playerModal.Question = $"{number1} x {number2}"; 
        }
        public async void StartTimer()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000); // wait 1 sec
                playerModal.TimeReaming--;

                if (playerModal.TimeReaming == 0)
                {
                    if (playerModal.Score > playerModal.HighScore)
                    {
                        playerModal.HighScore = playerModal.Score; // Update high score
                    }
                    GameOver(); // Finish the game when time is up
                }
            }
        }

        public void SubmitAnswer()
        {
            if (int.TryParse(playerModal.Answer, out int userAnswer))
            {
                int correctAnswer = int.Parse(playerModal.Answer);
                if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
                {
                    playerModal.Score += 10;
                    playerModal.TimeReaming += 5;

                }
                else
                {
                    playerModal.Score -= 10;
                    playerModal.TimeReaming -= 5;

                    // Negative score and time control
                    if (playerModal.Score < 0)
                    {
                        playerModal.Score = 0;
                    }
                    if (playerModal.TimeReaming < 0)
                    {
                        playerModal.TimeReaming = 0;
                    }
                }

                GenerateQuestion();
            }

            playerModal.Answer = "";

            // Check earned score and update new high score
            if (playerModal.Score > playerModal.HighScore)
            {
                playerModal.HighScore = playerModal.Score;
            }
        }

        public async void GameOver()
        {
           await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync(nameof(GameOverPage));
        }
    }
}
```

PlayerModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MauiApp2.Models
{
    public partial class PlayerModal : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        int score;
        [ObservableProperty]
        int highScore;
        [ObservableProperty]
        int timeReaming;
        [ObservableProperty]
        string answer;
        [ObservableProperty]
        string question;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are mixing up the public property and the private field

```
    // this is a public property named "PlayerDetail"
    [ObservableProperty]
    private PlayerModal _playerDetail;

    // this is not - there is really no need for this
    PlayerModal playerModal = new PlayerModal();
```

then you are setting properties on the wrong one - you should be using `PlayerDetail`, not `playerModal`

```
    public MultiplicationPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        playerModal.Score = 0;
        playerModal.TimeReaming = 60;
```

Comment: I changed the playerModal ones to PlayerDetail. This time, not working MultiplicationPage. where exactly do i need to change the codes? can you help me?

Comment: none of the properties of `PlayerModal` are `Observable`

Comment: I deleted the ```playerModal``` and changed all to ```playerDetail``` but it didn't work. I wonder if I should make ```playerModal```, ```Observable```? if the answer is yes how do i do it?

Comment: `playerDetail` is NOT the name of the public property you are binding to.  It is `PlayerDetail`.

Comment: ok as you said i changed all of them to ```PlayerDetail``` this time the page is not working at all

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the current state of your code

Comment: I update right now

Comment: You are not instantiating PlayerDetail anywhere

Comment: for example ```PlayerDetail.Score = 0;``` , ```PlayerDetail.TimeReaming = 60;``` Did I use it wrong here? where how should i use

Comment: PlayerDetail = new PlayerModal();

Comment: Yes it is, thank you. The data is reflected on the screen, but the counter does not advance, it is fixed at 60 and automatically writes the correct answer. When you press the Submit button, no new question or score comes up. I updated my question with a screenshot

Comment: did you fix the issue I pointed out in the 2nd comment?

Comment: I tried to do it from the link you sent before, but I still couldn't make ```PlayerModal```,  ```Observable```. Would you do it for me?

Comment: no, because you haven't posted the code for that class.  Please show me what you have tried

Comment: I add this ```[ObservableProperty] private PlayerModal _playerDetail;``` This is the part that I understood and added. Did I do something wrong? Like I said, I'm really beginner level. I'm so sorry for my hard to understand.

Comment: the **properties of PlayerModal** that you want to update need to be `Observable`,  ie, `Score` and `TimeReaming`

Comment: I updated the screenshot and added the ```Observable``` you mentioned to ```Score``` and ```TimeReaming``` but nothing changed.

Comment: please do not post code as images.  The **properties that you need to dynamically update the UI** need to be `Observable`.  Please take the time to read the docs so you understand this.  It is a fundamental part of MVVM in MAUI

Comment: I've solved the problem, I'm so sorry for bothering you. I updated the code and screenshot. Now my question gives the answer automatically, I don't want it to do that. Can you help me how can I solve this?

Comment: `GenerateQuestion` populates the `Answer` field.  You probably do not want to store the users answer and the "correct" answer in the same field

Comment: Whether the answer is right or wrong, my score and counter are constantly increasing. Idont want this. Can you help me how to code it to increase when I get it right and decrease when I get it wrong?

Comment: please look at your code in `SubmitAnswer`.  It will **always** match.  If you can't figure it out, please post a new question.